# Drawing Polygons on Google Maps using AngularJS and JSON stored coordinates

Tags: json, angularjs, google-maps

I have multiple JSON files (poly1.json, poly2.json) with the following setup:

```
{
  "Polygon1": {
    "name": "poly1",
    "specifications": [
      {
        "areaGeometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                5.129820025,
                52.085407733
              ],
              [
                5.129117875,
                52.086181679
              ],
              [
                5.128497179,
                52.087946286
              ],
              [
                5.128458022,
                52.088253322
              ],
              [
                5.12866837,
                52.088507157
              ],
              [
                5.129251266,
                52.088976802
              ],
              [
                5.129473861,
                52.08926905
              ],
              [
                5.129385309,
                52.089499203
              ],
              [
                5.12909759,
                52.089698198
              ],
              [
                5.127961124,
                52.090148712
              ],
              [
                5.127685173,
                52.090462912
              ],
              [
                5.127310682,
                52.091653473
              ],
              [
                5.12710699,
                52.092271708
              ],
              [
                5.127126612,
                52.092518366
              ],
              [
                5.128237531,
                52.093468305
              ],
              [
                5.128130926,
                52.093688728
              ],
              [
                5.126525853,
                52.094399058
              ],
              [
                5.126377274,
                52.09459342
              ],
              [
                5.126284571,
                52.095035437
              ],
              [
                5.130996578,
                52.095312264
              ],
              [
                5.137138625,
                52.095591962
              ],
              [
                5.139036247,
                52.095628598
              ],
              [
                5.138962372,
                52.095484813
              ],
              [
                5.137879856,
                52.093651573
              ],
              [
                5.137480747,
                52.093048367
              ],
              [
                5.136997815,
                52.092468872
              ],
              [
                5.13643473,
                52.091917507
              ],
              [
                5.135795776,
                52.091398471
              ],
              [
                5.134288171,
                52.090401311
              ],
              [
                5.133608279,
                52.089984575
              ],
              [
                5.133259679,
                52.089768435
              ],
              [
                5.132932239,
                52.089549796
              ],
              [
                5.132656508,
                52.089342179
              ],
              [
                5.132411195,
                52.089120552
              ],
              [
                5.132198186,
                52.088886599
              ],
              [
                5.132143714,
                52.088818019
              ],
              [
                5.130950838,
                52.087097103
              ],
              [
                5.130737143,
                52.086736442
              ],
              [
                5.130575274,
                52.086365674
              ],
              [
                5.130403794,
                52.085570404
              ],
              [
                5.129783706,
                52.08522338
              ],
              [
                5.129820025,
                52.085407733
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Now I want to draw all the polygons on Google Maps on where the user is looking at -if there is a polygon in his screen. What is the best way to do so? Should I use for each or are there better ways? How do you iterate over it? Would that not make it slow?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, there are two ways you can go about it. First, you can make a [KML layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer). You can put together all these polygons in one [KML file](https://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html) and make an overlay and integrate that overlay with your map object. (Here's the [JQuery](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/11-layers/kmllayer-45) reference)

Another way to do it is by using your JSON files and making a data layer. I would suggest to use the drag and drop GeoJSON code example as a reference. Because that will give you accuracy to the specific points. But you can always go for the simpler implementation, you can find other sample codes from Google on the left side of this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dragndrop).